# How to use vue-resource in simple project which uses vue js cdn(not Vue Cli)

Tags: vue.js

I'm using `Vue.js` in my `PHP project` as a CDN (it's not a vue Cli project).

I want to use `vue-resource` to connect one of my vue methods to my ApiController but i don't know how to use this package in a js file.

By the way when i import it like this: `import vueResource from 'vue-resource'`
i get this error : `Cannot use import statement outside a module`

```
   import vueResource from 'vue-resource'
   use(vueResource);

    new Vue({
        el:'#panel-main-wrapper',
        data : {
            collapse:false
        },
        methods:{
            loadCities(field){
                this.$http.post('/api/getCities',{
                    'name' : this.$refs[field].value
                }).then(function (data){
                    alert(data)
                })
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: You can use it as a CDN: `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-resource@1.5.1"></script>`

Comment: https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource#cdn